# what are practical uses of stdbuf or nohup?

Tags: bash, scripting, nohup, coreutils

I have to finish a writeup of a few coreutils commands for a course at the moment, and I can't think of a starting point for a small practical code example that demonstrates the potential uses of `stdbuf`.
Has anyone used it to fix the interaction of a couple specific unix commands?
I know what it does.
It's just that the first commands that came to mind have their own buffering controls, and normal terminal output is line buffered anyway.
It must be popular for appending to logs, yet I can't find a good command to demonstrate there.

In the case of `nohup`, are there any commands that are commonly run with it to prevent interruption?

As I mentioned, I am working on this for a course assignment at the moment. 
This however doesn't violate any of its rules.
I'm just trying to find a good starting point for these examples.
I don't have one for `stdbuf`, and I dislike the rudimentary one I was using for `nohup`.

Comment: For stdbuf: *normal terminal output is line-buffered anyway* - very true, which makes it really annoying when you want line-buffered output for a pipeline of *3* or more connected processes. Like `<infile grep1 | sort | grep3` or `<infile nl -bp... | sort -nk1,1` *because `nl` doesn't have any line-buffering options*.

Comment: These two utilities have nothing to do with each other, so you should ask these two questions separately. For nohup, why don't you like the presentation on Wikipedia?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

stdbuf examples at http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/

nohup is used for any long running command that you want left running across logins. You can also do this with screen(1) or retroactively with screen + https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr

Comment: Yeah I actually read that page on stdio buffering. Prior to the other answer it was just difficult to imagine a simple example. I was unaware that nohup persists across logins, and I couldn't think of many long running processes outside of daemons, which are typically launched by startup scripts.

Answer (score 4):

Let's start with an example without `stdbuf`. You need 2 terminals because `tail -f` will block.

Terminal 1

```
touch log_file1
tail -f log_file1 | cut -d " " -f 1 | uniq
```

Terminal 2

```
echo "A 1" >> log_file1
```

You don't see any output in Terminal 1.

Let's try again and add `stdbuf` to Terminal 1.

```
touch log_file2
tail -f log_file2 | stdbuf -oL cut -d " " -f 1 | uniq
```

Terminal 2

```
echo "A 1" >> log_file2
```

This time you should see `A` in Terminal 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [a concrete example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41841527/why-printf-does-not-output-to-a-file-when-stdout-is-redirected-to-that-file)

```
stdbuf -oL ./a.out > log.txt
```

Only when `stdbuf` is used, the printout can be piped into file.

Comment: Please include the relevant details from the linked question; `a.out` could be anything, and your answer on its own doesn’t explain why `stdbuf` is needed.